# carthage bootstrap giving parse error

Tags: carthage

I'm trying to run the following command

```
carthage bootstrap --platform iOS --no-use-binaries
```

But the process always fails with a parse error that doesn't give me much information. I'm not really sure where to go from here as the error doesn't give much information. Below is the full output.

```
*** Checking out Agrume at "78c2876f6d76cf706f55e42a1ca23154c67d174b"
*** Checking out Alamofire at "3.4.1"
*** Checking out Async at "1.7.2"
*** Checking out aws-sdk-ios at "2.4.5"
*** Checking out BRYXBanner at "0.6.0"
*** Checking out CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout at "fcea9e89faa984e1eb59c9f691c258f6f8004290"
*** Checking out CryptoSwift at "0.5.1"
*** Checking out css-layout at "dd8e5cd65d13a7da52502549cd8e514a345c5d23"
*** Checking out Decodable at "v0.4.3"
*** Checking out FormatterKit at "2ea246ae4573538886ffb946d70d141583443734"
*** Checking out Gifu at "v1.2.1"
*** Checking out HanekeSwift at "v0.10.1"
*** Checking out Infinity at "1.0.5"
*** Checking out JLRoutes at "1.6"
*** Checking out KMNavigationBarTransition at "065d635991674a3c1a03de3ccb9d0ee05b7aff65"
*** Checking out Locksmith at "2.0.8"
*** Checking out MTBBarcodeScanner at "2.0.2"
*** Checking out Permission at "v1.5"
*** Checking out PocketSVG at "0.7"
*** Checking out Result at "2.1.2"
*** Checking out ReactiveCocoa at "v4.2.1"
*** Checking out RxSwift at "2.6.0"
*** Checking out Moya at "6.5.0"
*** Checking out SwiftSVG at "v1.1.5"
*** Checking out SwiftyUserDefaults at "2.2.0"
*** Checking out Tactile at "v1.2.2"
Parse error: expected submodule commit SHA in output of task (ls-tree -z v1.2.1 Carthage/Checkouts/Runes) but encountered:
```

Comment: I'm currently getting the same issue.

Comment: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1384 (I know this is you, just adding for posterity)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on my project. For me it worked when I removed the lines associated with the error library from .gitmodules file.